# how to isolate a file's css from another file's css in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

We are currently working on a project where,
project structure demo:
[image]

whenever i use pdf.js and pdf.css in seperate project then it works perfectly.But when i put that pdf js and css inside this project ,then the css of the projects overriding the pdf.css

is there any way to use separate  css files each component?
i have tried doing modules.css ,but i have to change the existing all css for that,
please provide some suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference to [React's docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/#buttonjs). Basically you need to name your file `{file_name}.module.css`, where the file extension needs to end with `module.css`

Then you can use like this, as shown on React example:

Class based component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    // reference as a js object
    return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>;
  }
}
```

Functional base component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './Button.module.css'; // Import css modules stylesheet as styles
import './another-stylesheet.css'; // Import regular stylesheet

const Button = () => {
  return <button className={styles.error}>Error Button</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it's a good solution,i've tried in this way earlier,but in this case it is not working for some reason